# Set the value in the model so that when inserting or updating automatically added to the database in laravel?

Tags: laravel

In the database I have columns: `id, name, order, createdAt, updatedAt, createdBy, updateBy` .

In controller : **PostController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $req = Validator::make($request->all(), [
       'name' => 'required',
       'order' => 'required',
   ]);
   if ($req->fails()) {
      return response()->json(['error' => $req->errors()], 400);
   }
   $data = $request->all(); // name and order
   Post::insert($item);
}
```

I want when I add data. Then `createAt` column and `createBy` column will be added. Instead of setting `date('Y-m-d H:i:s)` and `$request->user()->id` in controller, Then I want it to be placed in `model`, when i insert `createAt` and `createBy` columns are added. If it's `update` then I want the `updatedAt` and `updatedBy` columns to be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add both createdAt and updatedAt in your migration file.
That will insert the current timestamp while inserting values into the table without adding them into the controller.
Please try like this while adding migration

```
Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->timestamp('createdAt');
   $table->timestamp('updatedAt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `POST::insert($data);` you could create/update a model more explicitly.

To add a new Post with only `createdAt` and `createdBy` you could do something like this:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->createdAt = $dateTime;
$post->createdBy = $userId;
$post->save();
```

Of course you can set any other attributes you are wanting to include before you save. And your `updatedAt` and `updatedBy` columns will have to be nullable in the database so that you don't get an error when you try to insert a record without including them.

Also as a note, Laravel has a feature that includes `created_at` and `updated_at` columns if you have: `$table->timestamps();` included in your table's migration file. These fields will get automatically updated whenever a database entry is created/updated.

Answer (score 0):

in your migration, you can just use the timestamps, it by default creates created_at and updated_at, and when you update an entry, Eloquent will update the value automatically for you, as for the created_by and updated_by, you can create them as well in migration, then setup an observer to set the values on create/update

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers